# Iterating over a two dimensional array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array, iteration

Just need a little bit of help iterating over a 2-dimensional array in Ruby.

If I have the following 2-d array:

```
a = [[1,2,3], 
     [4,5,6], 
     [7,8,9]]
```

Say [1,2,3] across are 'rows' and [1,4,7] down are 'columns'.

Say I have another array:

```
b = [3,6,9]
```

How can I iterate over a to see if [3,6,9] is a column in a?

Comment: An array does not match a string. A string can match a string or a regex. What do you really mean?

Comment: Do you mean that the concatenation of the elements in the array matches a string?  Do they have to be in order?  Please provide more details.

Answer (score 8):

You'll want to use [Array#transpose](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose).

```
a = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
b = [3,6,9]
a.transpose.include?(b) # => true

b = [3,6,7]
a.transpose.include?(b) # => false
```